# Load new video automatically when VideoJS MP4 ends

Tags: javascript, html, video.js

In a project I am currently working on, I have a VideoJS player which I want to change the source of when the video ends.
Using the VideoJS API, I am able to get a Javascript script to run when the player has reached an 'ended' state, but I can't find any code in their documentation or on StackOverflow explaining how to do this.

HTML

```
<video
id="my_video_1"
style="display:block;"
class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-nofull vjs-big-play-centered"
controls autoplay preload="none"
width="800px"
poster='res/img/poster.jpg'
data-setup='{ "fluid": true, "sources": [{ "type": "video/mp4", "src": "res/vid/vid1.mp4"}] }'
>
</video>
```

Is there any way of dynamically changing the src to a new file when the video ends?

Answer (score 2):

The VideoJS has an API of 'player.on' which is then followed by whichever listener is needed - in this case, ('ended').
Where I was falling down was that I was trying to use document.GetElementByID and update the src that way.

By changing the VideoJS code in the HTML to the style above, I was able to run the below listening event to update the src on ended and load a new video.

The next issue I had was the video was looping.  When the video ended, the same function was called infinitely.
To counter this, I added a Boolean value of 'executed' which changes to True on the first play.

```
<script>
    var video = videojs('my_video_1').ready(function(){
      var player = this;
      var executed = false;
      player.on('ended', function() {
        if (!executed) {
        player.src({"type":"video/mp4", "src":"res/vid/vid2.mp4"});
        player.play(); 
        executed = true 
        }
      });
    });
</script>
```

The first video now plays, followed by the second one when the first has finished without any user interaction.

I hope this helps anyone else who may experience a similar issue.